# android studio does not have android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I trying to edit my xml file but android studio cannot seems to find `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`

Comment: did you add com.android.support:design: lib in your gradle file?

Answer (score 2):

Add dependencies inside your **build.gradle** file:

```
 dependencies {
    // add this dependencies
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
 }
```

Comment: Yes i did, but it told me could not find method compile() for argument

And just to double confirm under which gradle i suppose to add in 
?

Comment: Can you paste your logcat and  build.gradle Dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

to fix this in Android Studio (AS) Build->Clean Project . Make sure in your build.gradle file under dependencies that you have:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:your_api_version_number.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:+'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! I placed the compile code under project where it should be module! Apologize ! and thank you for your help! hehe

Comment: Hello. This is a friendly comment to let you know why I downvoted your answer. It is not an answer and should be typed as a comment instead.

Comment: yeap okie sure understood